# Setting zoom level

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there any way I can set the zoom level between zoom levels 5 and 6? I can't select 5.5.

```
 map = new Map( "map" , {
                basemap: "gray",
        center: [-85.416, 49.781],
                zoom : 5,
                logo: false
        });
```

Comment: did any of the answers suit your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, as you are calling an ESRI created basemap, the simple answer would be no. The available zoom levels (or Levels of Detail) are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, and 16. If you look at the [ArcGIS Services Directory](http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer) for the [Gray Basemap](http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=8b3d38c0819547faa83f7b7aca80bd76) you can see the Levels of Detail listed.

You can take a look at the Javascript API documentation which outlines [Levels of Detail (LOD)](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/lod.html). The [Cache Levels](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/dotNet/index.htm#what_is_map_caching.htm) determine the Level of detail available. You can also read the [Slider with Labels](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/mapconfig_customlabels.html) sample which explains how the LODs are determined and how to call them.

The FLEX language has a reduced ability to [add LODs for extra zooming](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/flex/sample-code/add-lods-for-extra-zooming.htm) if you want. However, FLEX is no longer supported so you will be treading in uncharted territories after you create your map.

If you have ArcGIS Server you can develop your own cache levels and provide the resolution. However, you would still not be able to call level 5.5. You would need to determine at the Resolution and Scale for level 5.5 and label it as level 5.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. When using tiled services the map snaps to the nearest zoom level.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see a fractional zoom with the ArcGIS Javascript API, although I haven't used it before. Perhaps [rubber band zoom](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#isrubberbandzoom)?

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't give alternative suggestions, if you are specifically looking for fractional zoom levels.